# Make every citation in separate square bracket

Tags: citing

Right now I have

> [1-3] [3] [1,2]

But I need

> [1]-[3] [3] [1],[2]

How I can do that by altering just settings, but not the actual code?

MWE for this question is following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cite{Ruelle:71,Swinney:85,Andronov:37} \cite{Andronov:37} \cite{Ruelle:71,Swinney:85} 

\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
\bibliography{bibliographiclist}

\end{document}
```

Other used files: [bibliography](https://vk.com/doc100600701_504568302?hash=efee4c9c87476d95cc&dl=8ac17b05f324b7baab), [citation style](https://vk.com/doc100600701_504568298?hash=eb9c8f944358176267&dl=b5a1b592afa0b1369f).

Comment: But remember that "possible" does not mean "convenient".

Comment: What bibliography and citation package are you using? Ideally you would show us that in a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), because that would give us a starting point. Can you tell us how you cite so far? What exactly do you mean by altering settings as opposed to actual code (do you mean that you are OK with changes in the preamble but want to keep on using `\cite` as-is in the document body - or something else)?

Comment: @moewe, thanks for your responce! MWE is added now.

Comment: `\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `cite` package, you can redefine `\citeleft`, `\citeright` (the delimiters/parentheses around the complete list) and `\citeform` (the format of a single citation in the list).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}

\renewcommand\citeleft{}
\renewcommand\citeright{}
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}

\begin{document}
\cite{inbook-full,book-full,article-full}

\cite{article-full}

\cite{inbook-full,book-full} 

\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]–[3]//[3]//[1],[2]]